# python geopandas: jitter overlapping points

Tags: python, points, geopandas, jitter

I have some points with the same coordinates in a geodataframe, that I would like to randomly move a bit to avoid overlapping. Is there a simple way to do that with geopandas?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58473623/jitter-function-on-geographic-coordinates-latitude-longitudes/58473878#58473878

Comment: Thanks, that would solve part of the question. In my case, I have a geometry column and not all points are in groups. I plot the graphs externally, so I would need to change the data.